# KVM Image consumes more space on disk than what du shows

Tags: filesystems, kvm-virtualization

I have a kvm image which by looking at it with du -sh consumes 13GB (12980888) but in reality it consumes 42GB. Found that out the hard way when I scped it and after 18GB it was still copying something...

```
  Size: 42949672960 Blocks: 25961776   IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fe04h/65028d    Inode: 1310824     Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2014-09-12 09:19:53.016929149 +0200
Modify: 2014-09-12 09:18:47.364204306 +0200
Change: 2014-09-12 09:18:49.660229976 +0200
 Birth: -
```

How can this be? The partition I have this image on is normal ext4:
 /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)

The VM does not have any snapshots and it's shut down.

Comment: Probably a sparse file, which means that blocks that contain only zeroes aren't allocated on disk. Show the output of ls -ls on the original file, 1st number is 1k-blocks, compare to the size column. However scp will simply read the data and write the zeroes (which will allocate them). Try using rsync -S which handles sparse files specially.

Comment: use `qemu-img info IMAGENAME` next time

Comment: @wurtel - consider putting answers in the answer section so that questions can be marked as answered.  You have the right answer; get credit for that. :)